# Parsing file according to pair of ids and higher lower values

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

File1 has 8 columns. The column 3 and 4 make a pairing like rs|860  rs|756 and the values associated with the pair is at column 8.

```
bb  yy  rs|860  rs|756  xx  aa  0.7 2234
bb  yy  rs|310  rs|260  xx  aa  0.3 9838
bb  yy  rs|110  rs|77   xx  aa  0.5 2291
bb  yy  rs|756  rs|860  xx  aa  0.4 2269
bb  yy  rs|110  rs|77   xx  aa  0.9 1112
bb  yy  rs|756  rs|860  xx  aa  0.8 3269
bb  yy  rs|233  rs|79   xx  aa  0.4 1397
bb  yy  rs|79   rs|233  xx  aa  0.7 1397
```

The pair of column3 and 4 or 4 and 3 should be treated same for instance,  rs|860  rs|756  == rs|756  rs|860. Next, there might be repetition in the pairs in row one is also present in row4 and row6 (inversely). Simply here  AB = BA = BA. First I want to sort the col3 and col4 row-wise which can make data like AB = AB = AB. Next, in all the occurrence of the pairs only one should retain with maximum value at column8. FOr example, rs|860  rs|756 has maximum value at row6 (i.e., 3269) so the row1 and row4 should be deleted. Likewise in case of rs|110  rs|77 row5 should be deleted. Next, in case of pairs with similar value at column8, one with higher value at column7 should be retained. For example, in case of rs|233  rs|79 row7 with lower value at column7 (0.4) should be deleted. For any pair, if both the column8 and column7 have no higher/lower difference any one can be deleted.

The desired output File2

```
bb  yy  rs|260  rs|310  xx  aa  0.3 9838
bb  yy  rs|77   rs|110  xx  aa  0.5 2291
bb  yy  rs|756  rs|860  xx  aa  0.8 3269
bb  yy  rs|79   rs|233  xx  aa  0.7 1397
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-elegant `awk` solution:

```
{
    split($3, a, "|")
    split($4, b, "|")
    if (a[2] > b[2]){
        $3=b[1]"|"b[2]
        $4=a[1]"|"a[2]
    }
    split(arr[$3" "$4], c, " ")
    if ($8 > c[8]){
        arr[$3" "$4] = $0
    }
}
END{
    for (item in arr){
        print(arr[item])
    }
}
```

Run with

```
awk -f script.awk input
```

It does not retain the spacing and the ordering is random.

Comment: This doesn’t handle the `$7` rule.  The OP’s sample output shows that the `rs|79   rs|233` line should have `$7` = `0.7`, but your script gives `0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [pfnuesel’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381556/23408#381570),

```
{
    split($3, a, "|")
    split($4, b, "|")
    if (a[2] > b[2]){
        $3=b[1]"|"b[2]
        $4=a[1]"|"a[2]
    }
    key=$3" "$4
    split(arr[key], c, " ")
    if ($8 > c[8]  ||  ($8 == c[8] && $7 > c[7])){
        arr[key] = $0
    }
}
END{
    for (item in arr){
        print(arr[item])
    }
}
```

This assumes, as shown (but not explicitly stated) in the question,
that the values in the third and fourth columns are of the form

```
some_string | number
```

where spaces are for illustration only,
and the *string* does not contain any `|` characters. 
These tokens are to be sorted based on the values of the *number*s;
the *string* prefixes are not compared.

As in [pfnuesel’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381556/23408#381570), usage is

```
awk -f script.awk file1
```

The exact spacing of the input file is lost, but a readable column spacing can be (re)created by piping through  `column -t`; e.g.,

```
awk -f script.awk file1 | column -t > file2
```